# Report Builder - Total Expressions

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that displays the following data:

- Quantity
- Line Item Total/Extended Price (this is based off of a formula of rate * quantity)
- Product Type (i.e. Type A, B, C, D, & Other)

At the bottom of the report, I would like to add a small three column table that takes the total quantity and price by the product type.

The table will only ever have 5 rows - row 1 = Type A, etc.  Columns will be "Qty" and "Total" which should represent the sum of each based on the type.

I am struggling getting a RunningValue formula to work with a IIF statement that would filter based on type.

Here is what I have tried in cell A1 of the table (to display qty total for type a only):

```
=IIf(Fields!type.Value="A",RunningValue(Fields!quantity.Value, Sum, Nothing)
```

Comment: Still stumped on this, any help would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this it would be best to use a Matrix, as follows

1. Create a matrix and set the row grouping to be your Type Field.
2. Right click the column header and select Insert Column – Inside Group Left to give you two columns to display the Quantity and Total values.
3. In the header you can right click the area and selected Insert -> Rectangle, then added two text boxes to give the column headings (in blue)
4. In the left Dataset set the expression to be

   ```
   =sum(CInt(Fields!Qty.Value))
   ```

   To sum all the values for this Type together (Note this assumes the are integers, you can use `CDbl` for doubles for example)
5. Do the same for the Totals text box as well (note I have set the expression to return a currency as well – Right Cick -> Palaceholder Properties -> Number -> Currency)
6. This matrix looks as follows in design mode

   [image]

   And like this when rendered (note the source data I am using to generate this is also shown)

   [image]

Is this the sort of output you required?  Let me know if I can help further.